# How could IIS seemingly pull a web page out of thin air on my ASP.net WebForms application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I am contracted to support a legacy ASP.net WebForms application.  It's a commercial web site, and it's quite old.

Yesterday, I received a trouble-ticket that seemed to defy everything I know about web applications.

The trouble-ticket indicated that a certain URL sometimes returned an HTTP 404 error.  The submitter also swears that the problem only occurs when browsing the site with Chrome.  The web application is available in English and French, but the trouble-ticket says that the problem only occurs on the French version of the web application.

The URL looks like this:

http://www.example.com/promotion/mg_547/SpecialOffer.search

I tried navigating to the page in my development environment: http://www.example.dev/promotion/mg_547/SpecialOffer.search.  It seemed to work fine.

Although these URLs are fictionalized, "mg_547" is an actual directory name in the URL.

I decided to navigate to the file in Windows Explorer to see if there is something unusual about the file.  That's when things became surreal.

When I navigated to the "promotion" directory, I found that there is no "mg_547" directory (and besides, what meaning could such a name have?).  My understanding is that in an ASP.net WebForms application, URLs corresponding to files on a physical disk, but here, there is not file; there is no directory!

I checked that there isn't an "mg_547" virtual directory in IIS.

I carefully checked that there isn't an MVC controller hiding somewhere in the application and I reviewed the global.asax.cs file to see if there could be some unusual routing set up.  I couldn't find anything that would explain what I'm seeing.

I decided that the text of the page must appear in my code base somewhere, so I selected some text from the page (being sure that it didn't contain HTML-encodings) and searched for the text in the code-base; no matches!

Therefore, as far as I can tell, it seems as if the IIS server is just making up this page with Satanic Black Magic!

Comment: Have you any .ashx files in the code base - they can circumvent traffic?

Comment: Guessing: A [handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb515343(v=vs.100).aspx) for `.foo` "files" that don't have to exist or mapped to folder?

Comment: Just because you don't understand virtual directories or routing, that doesn't make it Satanic.

Comment: @John, I was being snarky.  I'm just saying that the behavior that I'm seeing is so different from what I've come to expect, it feels like magic.  Furthermore, as best as I can tell, virtual directories do not have to do with what I'm seeing.

Comment: `ASP.net WebForms application, URLs corresponding to files on a physical disk` not necessarily. Handlers, routing, virtual directories etc can make it not have a 1 to 1 relationship with the file system.

Comment: And, what version are you using, and, web site vs. web application, and have  you looked at the structure in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that I've found the answer. @EdSF's comment was very helpful.

There is a .net class called `PageHandlerFactory` which is overidden in the web application.  Specifically, this class overrides the `PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler` method.  The `mg_547` directory name is parsed in this overridden method and maps the URL to a different file on disk.

As for the original trouble-ticket that started all of this, perhaps there could be a bug in this method that causes the 404 error.

This is just as I expected.  This is a corner of ASP.net I've not yet become familiar with.